# Mock result of a hashSet

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am new to mocking help me to mock the result of check method
The mock should return false if the element is already in the hashSet
ps: i don’t want static testing

```
class A{
    HashSet<String> hash=new HashSet<>();
    public boolean check(String str){
        return hash.add(str);
    }
}
class ATest{
    //code to mock the check method
}
```

Comment: `A instance = new A(); when(instance.check(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(false);` You are welcome

Comment: A general rule of mocking is, "Don't mock what you don't own". Also, it's unusual to mock something as elemental as `Set`. I'd suggest mocking is not needed in this case.

Comment: if i try adding new string "a" two times in the ATest and think like hashSet is empty. It should return true in first call and false in second call

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to write tests for check() method, it does not seem the method needs to be mocked.
Let the HashSet handle the condition and the response in a way helps you to test the check() method.

So, this test should be enough:

```
    A a=PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
    @Test
    public void testSet() {
        boolean result1=a.check("1stString");
        boolean result2=a.check("1stString");
        
        assertTrue(result1);
        assertFalse(result2);
    }
```

But if you feel you need to mock[For whatever reason] the method and write tests, you can have two tests, one for verifying with single string and another for verifying duplicate.
Something like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testSet_singleEntry() {
        
        when(a.check("someString")).thenReturn(true);
        boolean result=a.check("someString");

        
        assertTrue(result);

    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSet_duplicateEntry() {
        //populate the set with the string once
        a.check("someString");
        
        //Now the expectation is that the check() method should return false if same string is passed again
        when(a.check("someString")).thenReturn(false);
        boolean result=a.check("someString");

        assertFalse(result);


    }
```

Of course the method param here are hardcoded which you would want to change and populate as per your test design.

Always remember, you mock a method when you already know what kind of output it will give based on conditions. In other words, you know the expected behaviour and thus writing the mock stub defining what to do when the method is called.